# ASPNET Identity ApplicationSignInManager will not resolve

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

The following code is giving me the error "Error    19  The base class or interface of 'MyProject.ApplicationSignInManager' could not be resolved or is invalid". I have custom versions of all identity classes with keys of type long, and they are all fine except signInManager.

```
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, long>
{
    public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var userManager = context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        return new ApplicationSignInManager(userManager, context.Authentication);
    }
}
```

Comment: In your Startup.auth do you have             app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create); ?

Comment: Yes, and I have tried with and without the same for ApplicationSignInManager